# paths.env not being replaced in GitHub workflow after deployment

Tags: github, deployment, workflow

I do have a `paths.env` file which contains two variables, `WORK_PATH` and `STORE_DATA_PATH`. I successfully deployed my code to Azure, using the following workflow (for simplicity, only posting the `build` part here)

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.8'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      - name: Update pip
        run: |
          python -m pip install --upgrade pip
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)
      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            release.zip
            !venv/
  create-env-file:
    needs: build  # Wait for the build job to complete
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: 'Create env file'
        run: |
          echo "WORK_PATH=$(pwd)" > paths.env
          echo "STORE_DATA_PATH=$(pwd)/store_data/" > paths.env
          cat paths.env
```

Why are `WORK_PATH` and `STORE_DATA_PATH` not being replaced?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. The actual behaviour of your `create-env-file` step is, that you override your `paths.env` file (first containing `WORK_PATH=$(pwd)`) with the second `echo` command. Where is this `paths.env` file coming from, and why does it contain the two variables?

Comment: Hi, ```paths.env``` contains the two variables. The idea is that these could be set locally, to anything you want, i.e ```Users/Username/Documents/MyProject```. The problem is that ```paths.env``` is not replaced in the workflow. The workflow intervenes when you deploy the app, but if I want to run the app on my computer, the workflow is not being called, so I need to manually set the variables to ```Users/Username/Documents/MyProject```. Perhaps I should manually set it to ```WORK_PATH=$(pwd)``` and ```STORE_DATA_PATH=$(pwd)/store_data/```, let's see if this gives any conflict.